# Inheritance when __new__() doesn't return instance of class

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, initializer

When `__new__` return instance of class, everything is ok, we can create subclass with no problems:

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, p1, p2):
        self = object.__new__(cls) 
        return self

    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, p3):
        self = super().__new__(cls, 1, 2)
        return self

    def __init__(self, p3):
        super().__init__(1, 2)
        self.p3 = p3

a = A(1, 2)    
print(a.p2)  # output: 2

b = B(3)
print(b.p3)  # output: 3
```

But,

> If `__new__()` does not return an instance of `cls`, then the new
>   instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.

Looks like we have to call `__init__()` inside `__new__()` directly, but this leads to error, when we call `super().__new__` in subclass:

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, p1, p2):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self.__init__(p1, p2)  # we should call __init__ directly
        return [self]  # return not instance

    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, p3):
        self = super().__new__(cls, 1, 2)
        return self

    def __init__(self, p3):
        self.p3 = p3

a = A(1, 2)    
print(a[0].p2)  # output: 2

b = B(3)  # TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
print(b[0].p3)
```

How to resolve it? How to create `A`'s subclass if `A.__new__()` doesn't return an instance of class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to call it manually, either don't name the method `__init__` and use per-class names instead, *or* manually call `__init__` methods unbound, directly on the class.

Per-class names are relatively easy, you can use double-underscores at the start to produce class-specific names through [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references):

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, p1, p2):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self.__init(p1, p2)  # call custom __init directly
        return [self]  # return not instance

    def __init(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, p3):
        self = super().__new__(cls, 1, 2)
        self[0].__init(p3)  # custom init
        return self

    def __init(self, p3):
        self.p3 = p3
```

or directly on the class:

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, p1, p2):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        A.__init__(self, p1, p2)  # call custom __init__ unbound
        return [self]  # return not instance

    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, p3):
        self = super().__new__(cls, 1, 2)
        B.__init__(self[0], p3)  # call custom __init__ unbound
        return self

    def __init__(self, p3):
        self.p3 = p3
```

If you are going this way, you may as well *do away* with a custom initialiser and just do your initialisation in `__new__` altogether:

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, p1, p2):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        return [self]  # return not instance


class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, p3):
        self = super().__new__(cls, 1, 2)
        self[0].p3 = p3
        return self
```

After all, you *already* have access to the instance at creation time, you may as well initialise it there and then.