# Inheritance when __new__() doesn't return instance of class in python 2.7.12

Tags: python, python-2.7, constructor

I've been reading about when `__new__()` doesn't return instance of class on stackoverflow [Inheritance when __new__() doesn't return instance of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392810/inheritance-when-new-doesnt-return-instance-of-class) and I know this question is for python 3. As Martijn Pieters states, it can be done by [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) and call it manually directly in the class and initialised it altogether in the class.

I want try it in python 2.7.12. The first and second approach I can manage, but for the third approach raises a `TypeError`.

This is my code, first attempt:

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, p1, p2):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        return [self]

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, p3):
        self = super(B,cls).__new__(cls,1,2)
        self[0].p3 = p3
        return self
```

This gives me `TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj`

Second attempt:

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, p1, p2):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        return [self]  #return not instance

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, p3):
        self = super(B,cls).__new__(cls,1,2)
        self[0].p3 = p3
        return self
```

This gives me `TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`.

Why does this happen, can this be implemented in python 2.7.12 or this technique incompatible?

Comment: Your second attempt works just fine for me. Did you forget to pass in an argument?

Comment: The other question is about how to call `__init__()` when a subclass has a different number of arguments for that method, as normally `__init__` will be called only *once*. You are doing nothing of the sort here, this is just simple `__new__` overriding.

Comment: yes i forget to pass in an argument

Answer (score 1):

In your first attempt, you are passing in an *old-style* class object, but `super()` only accepts new-style classes.

You need to inherit from `object` to get a new-style class, which you correctly did in your second attempt. You merely *forgot to pass in an argument* when creating an instance:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __new__(cls, p1, p2):
...         self = object.__new__(cls)
...         self.p1 = p1
...         self.p2 = p2
...         return [self]
...
>>> class B(A):
...     def __new__(cls, p3):
...         self = super(B, cls).__new__(cls, 1, 2)
...         self[0].p3 = p3
...         return self
...
>>> B()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
>>> B(42)
[<__main__.B object at 0x10241fa90>]
```

Your error told you that `B.__new__` wanted two arguments, but only `cls` was being passed in.

Comment: oh i see sir, it happend cause i call class B instance without p3 argument B() returns "TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" but with B(42) will give main B object. Thank you sir